# Wireshark REST analysis

Tags: rest, wireshark

I'm trying to figure out the communication between an iOS app, and an online server. To my knowledge, a REST service is used.
With a tricky setup with two macs, an ethernet hub and an iPhone, I manage to capture the traffic between the device and the server. 
So far so good. However, when I fire up the app, a trace is shown in Wireshark (also very good), but all that is listed is in TCP protocol, where I am expecting HTTP protocol. 
[image: see screen shot]
Now, I'm running out of knowledge.
Does this mean, that there is no HTTP communication going on at all, or am I seeing raw TCP packages that need to be assembled into HTTP? If the latter, how do I approach that, and will I ever see readable xml?
Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Right hand click on a packet > tcp > follow stream: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html. Also, wrong place to be asking...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this question became obsolete, since I found exactly what I wanted to do here:
http://nickfishman.com/post/50557873036/reverse-engineering-native-apps-by-intercepting-network